# Page 404 not found django

Tags: python, django

I was trying to do a 'add member' function. Basically,when you click on the button 'add button', member names will show somewhere in this page.But I got this error:

[image]

Here is part of HTML looks like:
[image]

project_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Project {{ project_id }} detail</p>
    <div class="btn btn-default oval" style="width: 10%"><a href="{% url 'project:project_edit' project_id=project_id%}">Edit</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default oval"style="width: 10%"><a href="{% url 'project:project_delete' project_id=project_id%}">Delete</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default oval"style="width: 10%">Members</div>
     <form action="" method="POST" id="selection-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                    <select id="member_list">
                            {% for user in users %}
                        <option value="{{user.id}}">
                            {{ user.username }}
                        </option>
                   {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                     <input type="button" value="Add member" id="selection-button">
                     </form>

                    <div id="res"> </div>


{% endblock %}


{% block script %}
    var url = $( '#selection-button' ).attr( 'action' );
    $("#selection-button").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value =$('#member_list').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'add_member/'+value+'/',
            success:function (result) {
                $("#res").append(value);
            },
            error:function (result) {
              alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

{%  endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_index, name='project_index'),
    path('<int:project_id>/', views.project_detail, name='project_detail'),
    path('create/', views.project_create, name='project_create'),
    path('<int:project_id>/delete/', views.project_delete, name='project_delete'),
    path('<int:project_id>/delete_result/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="project/delete_result.html"), name='delete_result'),
    path('<int:project_id>/edit/', views.project_edit, name='project_edit'),
    path('<int:project_id>/add_member/<int:user_id>', views.add_member, name='project_add_member'),

    path('<int:project_id>/task/', include('task_tracker.urls')),
    path('<int:project_id>/issue/', include('issue_tracker.urls',namespace='issue_tracker')),
    path('<int:project_id>/channel/', include('communication_channel.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
def add_member(request,project_id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        members = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer()
        return render(request,'project/project_add_member',{'project_id':project_id})
```

project_add_member.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>success!</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_member(request,project_id,user_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    form = User(request.POST)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = User(request.POST,instance=User)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('project:delete_index')
        else:
            form = User()
```

I could not figure out where I was wrong. It seems like it is the URL? Let me know if you need me to upload more code to identify the issue.

Comment: A 404 error indicates that something was not found. Are you sure the project with id 5 and the user with id 1 exist?

Comment: I think 'project/project_add_member' has to be 'project/project_add_member.html'. I just tried removing the ".html" in one of my project's view and django would throw a "template not found" error.

Comment: No. In mine is still 404 page not found  @Alexandre Cox 5

Comment: Your `urls.py` doesn't specify a trailing slash on the add member url. Remove the trailing slash in your JS `url:'add_member/'+value,` and you should get rid of the 404. FYI. It probably makes sense to always have a trailing slash in your urls.py since Django has a setting called [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash). If anyone is performing a request, django would automatically add a slash if no url can be resolved otherwise.

Comment: When I removed it, it gave me 403 forbidden error :/ . @blackwhite

Comment: Yes, that's good since it resolves the url now -> next challenge ;) You'll likely receive the 403 because you are missing a csrf token. You can either google for "how to include django csrf token in ajax request" or remove it via [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) for this single request **Disclaimer: Removing csrf check is a serious security issue and should never be done in production and when data is altered at the target system.**

Comment: Put it on view ? I did that, but it stills shows me 403 error @blackwhite

Answer (score 0):

Your view `add_member` should declare both URL arguments it receives:

Change

```
def add_member(request,project_id):
    ...
```

to

```
def add_member(request, project_id, user_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    ...
```

Comment: project id and user id is alright. This still gave the same error.I am wondering is it because of my url ?  @Ralf